# Copying Chart Objects From Excel to PP inconsistent results

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am creating a powerpoint presentation out of an excel document. As I create each slide, I am copying a chart object from a worksheet in the excel document. The charts are not being copied after the first one. If I include a message box after each chart, they are. I've tried including a delay between these copy/pastes as well as DoEvents and messed around with trying to clear the clipboard after each paste but nothing seems to be working. I'm wondering if somebody can enlighten me to why this is happening? I am using Excel 2010/PP 2010 - This is basically the same code I'm using for each slide..

```
'Slide #5
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(5, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
Set ttlBox = PPSlide.Shapes("Title 1")
Worksheets("worksheetname").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.ChartArea.Copy

With PPPres
.Windows(1).Activate
.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide 5
.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
End With

With PPSlide
  .Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=imagePath & "outlier.png", LinktoFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0
End With

With ttlBox
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 128)
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 175
    .Width = 545
    .Height = 70
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Losses"
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = "22"
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
End With

MsgBox ("Hi")
```

Comment: Pleas try to use either `.Windows(1).View.paste` or `.Windows(1).View.pastespecial ....` instead of `...ExecuteMso...`. Does it improve anything? But check it with `DoEvents` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using pastespecial, DoEvents and declaring my worksheet as an object seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Sure, it's acceptable and just what I needed.. Although now I am stuck on another issue. The reason I was using .Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") was because it was keeping my source formatting. PasteSpecial doesn't seem to keep all of my chart objects' original formatting. Is there a way to call this so that it acts the same as ExecuteMso?

Comment: Have you tried with all PasteSpecial parameters, like `ppPasteShape`, `ppPasteBitmap` or `ppPasteDefault` or others?

Comment: yeah - my original problem is solved and ppPasteShape worked. Now my problem is stopping it from crapping out - I seem to get about 8 or 9 slides in and powerpoint crashes.

Comment: Let's leave this question unanswered, now. Hopefully, @SteveRindsberg will be able to suggest something later in the day.

Comment: After a lot of testing different solutions - Using the Wait(1) command between copying and pasting was actually the solution. I was able to use ExecuteMso or view.pastespecial

Comment: in my opinion you can add an answer to your question presenting correct solution. This will be useful for others who have similar issue.

Comment: Okay - will do. Thank you for the help in finding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing different solutions - Using the Wait(1) command between copying and pasting was actually the solution.